# QueryDSL using SpringData repositories having performance impact on Mongo

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I am using QueryDSL and SpringData Repositories, while performing search on 3,00,000 documents it is taking time around 9 seconds. Search parameters are not indexed on Mongo.

And if iam using Mongo Query it is taking time in ms.
i have seen predicate construction happens in ms, only hitting the query and retrieving results are taking the time.

Is there any place where Performance of QueryDSL are listed?

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: 300,000 or 3,000,000 users?

Comment: As is, your question isn't specific enough to be answerable as a programming question on StackOverflow. You should add some examples of queries and `explain()` output. It sounds like your application code is asking the MongoDB server to search 300,000 documents without an index; is there a reason you can't [create indexes to support your queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/)? If the issue is because of queries generated by QueryDSL, you should be able to find these slow queries in your MongoDB log and work out how to improve their performance.

Comment: Which Querydsl version do you use? Also what is the difference of the serialized Mongodb queries if there is any?

Comment: I am using 2.9.0. I am using native queries using mongo driver.Its like string based queries. "person.gender.value" : /.*M/".But if i hit the same query using querydsl using objects it is taking lots of time.